# VBA coding workbook from readonly to read write accepting changes

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to VBA coding and i need help.

My overall target is to have the right coding that will allow me to

- Turn a read only workbook into a read-write workbook and
- Accept the changes made

I have the correct coding that allows me to complete the first bit (and so i can turn any read only workbook into a read write workbook) but this will not allow me to save the changes (only save as).

I have the ability to make this happen using authorization if needed, but can anyone help me with the needed code?

Thanks
Tim.

Comment: have you tried recording what you want to do using the macro recorder, then looking at the generated code?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the workbook in read-write mode, all you need to do is suppress the Save As prompt using `Application.DisplayAlerts`:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```